# Interpreting . (dot) in file checks in bash shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

I've got a function that I call to check on the existence of files (which has been greatly improved with the help of users like you), and the function breaks down if the user uses a . (dot) to represent the present working directory as their complete argument.

There's already a handle in there for interpreting ~ (tilde) in the path, so I thought it shouldn't be difficult to handle . (dot). Here is the current function:

```
    1  exist.fn() {
    2      local dir="$1"
    3      while [ ! -d "$dir" ]; do
    4        echo -e "\033[1m\"$dir\"\033[0m does not exist." >&2
    5        read -u2 -e -p "Enter a valid path: " dir
    6        dir="${dir/\~/$HOME}"
    7      done
    8      echo "$dir"
```

In any case, I thought I could just slip some little hack in like this at the top, and it would solve the problem:

```
      if [ "$dir" == '.' ]; then
        dir=$( pwd )
      fi
```

But, no dice. Anyone care to elaborate? I'm still curious as to why this way isn't working. Any and all input is appreciated.

[EDIT]: Okay, so that substitution on line 6 is a String Operation. Looking into this now.

Comment: `dir="${dir/\./$PWD}"` something like this ?

Comment: But how do I combine that with the `dir="${dir/\~/$HOME}"`

Comment: IF you want to do multiple substitution then probably , `sed` can help...

`dir=$(echo $dir |sed -e "s@\.@$PWD@ ; s@~@$HOME@")`  This will replace `~` with your home directory and `.` with your `pwd`.

Comment: dot `.` is a real name, it is not an alias or a shortcut - it is not a shell shortcut like tilde `~`.   So what is wrong with using it as a name?

Comment: You should not have to handle `.` that is valid directory. What's the output of `[ ! -d . ] ||  echo ". is directory"` in your terminal?

Comment: I think you are right @cdarke I thought it was not getting expanded somewhere b/c it might have been quoted and braced as a variable or something. But it seems like maybe the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I think you're right as well @Kenazov. `. is a directory` In any case, the only errors I'm getting back at the moment are from failed commands due to getting passed file names with spaces. But I feel like I've forgotten one of the tests I found to make it fail.

Comment: @PS. Thanks for the recommendation. I will try your sed expression when I get the chance. But I just did some searching and found out that what I was looking for on line 6 is a String Operation, so I'm going to edit my post.

Comment: If you want to check the existence of a file, why not `[[ -e $filename ]]` ?